# winforms C# подключение к базе данных в локальной сети

Tags: c#

уважаемые люди, помогите пожалуйста разобраться, на C# winforms создал приложения с база данных, создал несколько логин пароль для каждого пользователя , сервер MAMP,  теперь хочу тестировать эту приложению на другом компьютере через локальной сети , все компьютеры в одной подсети, не знаю как расшарить Базу данных  чтобы они могли заходит под свой логин пароль

Comment: Шарить базу данных по сети - плохая практика, к тому же как ваши приложения будут отслеживать изменения в базе, сделанные другими клиентами? Никак. А если это и не нужно, то можно залезть в вашу базу и испортить данные, если она будет доступна в сети. Вам нужно приложение-сервер, которое будет читать и писать базу, а клиенты будут с этим приложением общаться вместо того чтобы общаться с базой напрямую. Никто не шарит базу по сети, это небезопасно, но если очень хочется, то читайте документацию сервера базы данных.

Comment: aepot, спасибо вам за ценный совет ! еще если вам не трудно объясните пожалуйста, у меня приложения при входе запрашивает логин пароль , то есть у меня есть база данных пользователей, теперь как я могу дать доступ другим пользователем  доступ на мою приложению, т.к при входе нужно вводит логин и пароль , а они хранятся на базе данных , спасибо заранее !

Comment: Вы сначала разберитесь с тем, что я выше написал.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, просто хотел протестит приложения как работает на других компьютерах, т.к  я новичок данный момент

Comment: Вы можете запустить несколько приложений на одном компьютере, разницы никакой доступ к базе по сети решается только настройкой самой базы, установкой прав пользователю БД и настройкой сервера БД. Клиент лишь должен знать IP адрес базы и порт подключения.

Comment: (настройкой сервера БД. Клиент лишь должен знать IP адрес базы и порт подключения ) вот именно это и  хотел уточнить в вопросе , тоесть как настроит на клиенте IP и порт для подключения, если по этому вопросу есть какие то материалы , прощу,  дайте ссылки

Comment: https://zen.yandex.ru/media/tehnichka/kak-posmotret-ipadres-kompiutera-na-windows-10-5fd760f964f2df1897056e38

Comment: курс cisco CCNA пройден, все равно спасибо

Comment: Какой вопрос - такой ответ. У вас проблема вставить IP и порт сервера в строку подключения к базе, или что? Или погуглить за вас, как настроить базу, тип которой вы даже не назвали в вопросе? Вы не заботитесь о качестве своего вопроса, почему я должен заботиться о качестве своих подсказок?

Comment: строка подключения у меня настроена , есть сеть , 192.168.1.1 , есть 3 компьютера 192.168.1.104, 105, 106  .  сервер стоит на 192.168.1.104 ,  теперь я хочу протестить приложения на другом компьютере ( 192.168.1.5 и 192.168.1.106)  вот как коннектится от двух компьютеров к серверу с базой данных ,вопрос жизни

Comment: Точно так же как и с одного компьютера.

Comment: уважаемый aepot, спасибо вам за наводку , еще если можете объяснит такую ошибку буду очень благодарен !   при извлечении логин  и пароля  из БД пишет такую ошибку :MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Authentication to host '192.168.1.121' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'admin-admin' (using password: YES)"     строка подключения  выглядит так : MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.1.121;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=marytelekom");

Comment: Пользоваетелю не хватает прав подключиться

Comment: понятно, тоесть на самом MySql сервере надо прописать права для каждого юзера  ? или я не туда....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239145/12888024